# Removing names from column based on condition in Python

Tags: python, csv

Here is my input csv file:

```
column1             column2

abc city town      efg town
abc town city      efg city
efg town           abc city town
efg city           abc town city
```

I want to do if my csv file contains:

1) city only if exists in a row it should remove city

2) town only if exists in a row it should remove town

3) city town if exists it should remove only town

4) town city if exist it should remove only city

My desired output should look like:

```
column1             column2

abc city           efg 
abc town           efg 
efg                abc city 
efg                abc town
```

I am trying to do using Python. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = {"A": ['abc town', "abc city", 'abc town city', "abc city town"]}
for i in df['A']:
...     if i == 'town':
...             df['b'] == 'yes'
...             print (df)
```

I am stuck on if the row contains only city or town I have to remove that. I know there is a concept **contains all** where I can use that, but am not sure about it, on applying.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code

Comment: I tried using dataframe by giving if condition, but it is not working

Comment: Ok.  Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Use `if 'town' in i` instead of `if i == 'town'`. The latter checks if the two strings are identical, but the former checks if the string 'town' is in the other string, which is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple solution which i have tried,

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace(r'town$','')

df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace(r'city$','')
```

Likewise for column2 also

```
df['column2'] = df['column2'].str.replace(r'town$','')

df['column2'] = df['column2'].str.replace(r'city$','')
```

Output will look like this,

```
column1             column2

abc city           efg 
abc town           efg 
efg                abc city 
efg                abc town
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use Pandas module.  But i believe it does what you want.  Probably a much shorter way to accomplish this task though.

```
import csv

filename = 'file location and name'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

list1 = []

for x in data:
    for i in x:
        if i.count(' ') > 1:
            i = ' '.join(i.split(' ', 2)[:2])
            list1.append(i)
        else:
            i = i.split(' ')[0]
            list1.append(i)
list2 = list1[::2]
list3 = list1[1::2]

zipped_list = zip(list2,list3)
headers = ['header1', 'header2']

with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as csv_save:
    cw = csv.writer(csv_save)
    cw.writerow(headers)
    cw.writerows(zipped_list)
```

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: Please refer to my solution below.